# Skipping an element in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, contenteditable

Let's say we have the following text and caret position:

`foo |bar baz`

and the HTML code is

`foo <span>bar</span> baz`

and user pressed the right arrow key. What happens is that the caret now moved inside of the span between the letters `b` and `a` of `bar`.

I would like CKEditor to automatically skip a certain element (for example all spans) and jump behind it so the result would be:

`foo bar| baz`

Is this possible by only fiddling with the configuration? If so, what do I need to set? I wasn't able to find settings like these mentioned in the documentation. Or do I have to alter the CKEditor source code to be able to do stuff like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important thing is that CKEditor is not responsible for caret movements. At least this is true in most cases, because there are some where it takes matters in its own hands. In all other cases it's your browser what moves the caret so you would need to alter its behaviour. This is doable and it simply requires writing a `keydown` listener which will discover when a certain situation happens and set selection in your chosen location. However, that's not all, because user may also place caret inside such `<span>` by clicking or by dragging. So there's a little (well... "little") bit more to do.

Another solution is to use non-editable islands which in CKEditor are called widgets. I'm not sure if this is what you want to achieve, but perhaps [placeholders](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/placeholder.html) are what you're looking for.

If you want to read more about widgets in general see – [Introduction to Widgets](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_widgets).

Comment: Well there are two conditions. The text inside the element should not be edited and also user shouldn't be able to place the caret inside of such elements. Which of the mentioned solves this? Could you provide some sample code, please?

Comment: Did you see the [demo of placeholders](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/placeholder.html) to which I linked in my answer?

Comment: I don't mean to be unthankful, but with 40k+ points you could be familiar with the "link only answer" policy over here. For the sake of  future viewers please add the relevant code. I am ready to accept the answer.

Comment: I'm afraid we understand what a ["link only answer"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) is very differently. You didn't ask how to install or use a placeholder plugin. You asked a conceptual question how to solve a certain problem. Hence, my answer is also conceptual. It mentions two alternative solutions without going into details which would require (in the 1st case) around a thousand lines of code. In other words – the value of my answer is in the information I gave you and it is the information you asked for.